# sqlalchemy + async: Problem with inserting data

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write to DB in a async mode, but for some reason, values are not stored. However tables are created.

My DB

```
async def create_tables(self):
     async with self.async_engine.begin() as conn:
            await conn.run_sync(self.models.Base.metadata.drop_all)
            await conn.run_sync(self.models.Base.metadata.create_all)
    
    async def connect(self):
        conn_str: str = self.__create_connection_str()
       
        # ASYNC
        self.async_engine = create_async_engine(conn_str)
        self.session_factory = sessionmaker(
            self.async_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=False, autoflush=False
        )
      
           

    def create_async_session(self):
        session = self.session_factory()
        try:
            yield session
        finally:
            session.close()
```

create_async_session returns:

> <generator object DatabaseHandler.create_async_session at 0x000001C148797840>

My insert function:

```
async def create_artist(session: AsyncSession, artist: schemas.Artist):
        try:
            # map values
            db_artist = models.Artist(
                artist_id=artist.id,
                name=artist.name,
                href=artist.href,
                genres=artist.genres,
                popularity=artist.popularity,
                type=artist.type,
                uri=artist.uri,
                external_urls=artist.external_urls["spotify"],
                followers=artist.followers["total"]
            )

            print(db_artist) # -> returns values ok
            print(session) # -> returns value

            await session.add(db_artist)
            await session.commit()
            await session.refresh(db_artist)

            return artist
        except Exception as err:
            err
```

My main func:

```
async def collect_artists_in_background():
    await db_client.connect()
    await db_client.create_tables() # -> works

    session = db_client.create_async_session() # -> works

    for _id in list_of_artists_ids:
        artist = await crud.get_artist_by_id(_id) # -> works
        await CRUD.create_artist(session, schemas.Artist.parse_obj(artist)) # -> doesn't work
```

I think the ploblem is in create_async_session, but I can't get where

I have tried to create a fixed session, not yield

```
async with db_client.session_factory() as session:
        for _id in list_of_artists_ids:
            artist = await crud.get_artist_by_id(_id)
            await CRUD.create_artist(session, schemas.Artist.parse_obj(artist))
```

But it also doesn't work

Comment: `create_async_session` seems like it was supposed to be used in a fastapi like framework, what is the error you are getting? the "fix" is to use `session = next(db_client.create_async_session())` I guess if you want it to work this way

Comment: @python_user I do use fastapi, but I have to populate a DB table at first and then user can make requests. The collect_artists_in_background function returns no error

Comment: if you are using fastapi, then you must be aware of "dependency injection" and fastapi supports generators for dependency injection, the way you are using it now does not make sense for a standalone function, you have to either use the "fix" I mentioned or ideally create a new function that "returns" a session instead of yielding, for use here. what is the error you are getting now?

Comment: you mention it returns no error, can you confirm that?

Comment: @python_user
 I have tried insted of session = db_client.create_async_session() # -> works, use  async with db_client.session_factory() as session: stuff. But it also not works. I am not getting an error

Comment: what is the database you are using? if its sqlite, can you show the connection string?

Comment: @python_user

MY DB is psql, and the thing is, that tables are actually created and therefore the connecion exists.    

session = next(db_client.create_async_session())

Here I get -> 

session.close()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: `await session.close()` but other than that I am not sure

Comment: can you do a change, the reason you get no error is because you capture all exceptions and do nothing, can you re-raise the error in `except Exception as err: raise err` and then show what is it that you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing the session you can try something like :

```
def create_async_session(self):
 with self.session_factory() as session:
  {do something}
```

with the 'WITH' operator your session gets closed after the operation.